# How do I integrate ESLint and Prettier?

Tags: eslint, prettier

I'm having trouble using both ESLint and Prettier together. What are the steps needed to get them to work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Install ESLint and Prettier.

```
$ npm install --save-dev eslint prettier
```

2) Install the plugins and configurations that enable them to work together.

```
$ npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier
```

3) Add the following to your ESLint config file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

4) Add the `lint` and `prettier` commands as npm scripts to `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'",
    "prettier": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.js'",
    "check-all": "npm run prettier && npm run lint",
    ...
  }, 
}
```

5) Now you can lint and prettify your code at the same time by doing:

```
$ npm run check-all
```

Or invoke them separately:

```
$ npm run lint
$ npm run prettier
```